# Problem while installing Globaleaks with Docker | Permission denied in docker volume

Tags: python, linux, docker, installation

so I tried to install the docker version of Globaleaks.
The container is running in a restart-loop right after executing the **docker-compose up -d** command.

I inspected the logs of the container and I received the following logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/globaleaks", line 88, in <module>
    State.init_environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 108, in init_environment
    self.create_directories()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 149, in create_directories
    self.create_directory(dirpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 135, in create_directory
    raise excep
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 131, in create_directory
    os.mkdir(path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/globaleaks/files'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/globaleaks", line 88, in <module>
    State.init_environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 108, in init_environment
    self.create_directories()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 149, in create_directories
    self.create_directory(dirpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 135, in create_directory
    raise excep
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 131, in create_directory
    os.mkdir(path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/globaleaks/files'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/globaleaks", line 88, in <module>
    State.init_environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 108, in init_environment
    self.create_directories()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 149, in create_directories
    self.create_directory(dirpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 135, in create_directory
    raise excep
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 131, in create_directory
    os.mkdir(path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/globaleaks/files'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/globaleaks", line 88, in <module>
    State.init_environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 108, in init_environment
    self.create_directories()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 149, in create_directories
    self.create_directory(dirpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 135, in create_directory
    raise excep
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 131, in create_directory
    os.mkdir(path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/globaleaks/files'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/globaleaks", line 88, in <module>
    State.init_environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 108, in init_environment
    self.create_directories()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 149, in create_directories
    self.create_directory(dirpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 135, in create_directory
    raise excep
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 131, in create_directory
    os.mkdir(path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/globaleaks/files'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/globaleaks", line 88, in <module>
    State.init_environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 108, in init_environment
    self.create_directories()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 149, in create_directories
    self.create_directory(dirpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 135, in create_directory
    raise excep
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 131, in create_directory
    os.mkdir(path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/globaleaks/files'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/globaleaks", line 88, in <module>
    State.init_environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 108, in init_environment
    self.create_directories()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 149, in create_directories
    self.create_directory(dirpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 135, in create_directory
    raise excep
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 131, in create_directory
    os.mkdir(path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/globaleaks/files'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/globaleaks", line 88, in <module>
    State.init_environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 108, in init_environment
    self.create_directories()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 149, in create_directories
    self.create_directory(dirpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 135, in create_directory
    raise excep
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/state.py", line 131, in create_directory
    os.mkdir(path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/globaleaks/files'
```

**Can anyone help me with that ?**

I expected that the docker container would run as usual.

Comment: Define the scenario properly so others -- willing to help -- can reproduce or better understand what you have at hand. For instance, it would help providing the docker-compose file you're using. Also, what is "Globaleaks"?...help others help you ;)

Answer (score -1):

This worked on my system, I'm not sure if it will work on yours but you can try:

Make sure that the directory is writable:

```bash
docker exec -it globaleaks ls -l /var/globaleaks
```

Make sure the container can make directories:

```bash
docker exec -it globaleaks mkdir /tmp/test
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, i tried to run the command with sudo already, but it doesn't work.

Comment: No worries, not sure what else it could be.

Comment: @tombiebl I changed the answer with something that worked on my system, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I can't run this command because if I start my container it immediately is in a restart loop: Error response from daemon: Container 65092def753aaa42db15c97a9fdcd27064e839ab85a53207d01b2930e4fadbcd is restarting, wait until the container is running

Comment: Anything you do with `docker exec` will be lost as soon as the container exits.  A better solution would propose a change to the Dockerfile, maybe adding a `RUN mkdir ...` line if you've identified that missing directory is the problem.